# Simple Angular 2 project fails 'Unexpected reserved word'

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a simple Angular2 project based on the ng2do project. I am using the quickstart and I have the following code...

```
<script src="js/quickstart/dist/es6-shim.js"></script>

....
import {Component, Template, bootstrap, Foreach} from 'js/quickstart/angular2/angular2';
```

This gives me the following error...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you compiled the es6 source to es5?

Comment: Not sure I thought that was what the shim is doing. The ng2do project doesn't seem to do any precompiling

Comment: You have to compile before putting it in the browser. Use `traceur`: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler

Comment: Are you sure this isn't already done with the quickstart repo?

Comment: Angular2 itself is precompiled, not the code you write for it.

Comment: So then why is there no trace of it here https://github.com/davideast/ng2do and this works fine

Comment: My bad, the shim seems to handle it. `todo.js` is converted to `todo.js!eval` which runs. Try writing your code in todo.js.

Comment: This is essentially the same thing that I am doing with minor caveats for example the way he is loading the todo.js file. I need to load many components so 1 is going to do me no good and I don't want to create an entry for each. Another good source for info is the examples under angular/angular/modules/examples on github. Changing the file name is not going to help though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73182/discussion-between-jackie-and-kedar).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps I have been having this issues all day realised it was because I was starting my code with a script reference

```
<script src="app.js">
</script>
```

instead of using

```
<script>
   System.import('app');
</script>
```

Hope this helps also using this in tsconfig

```
{
    "version": "1.5.0-beta",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./main.ts",
        "./show-properties.ts",
        "./typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts",
        "./typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts",
        "./typings/rx/rx-lite.d.ts",
        "./typings/rx/rx.d.ts"
    ]
}
```